# How do I use a function to insert a cell value into another cell?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

[image]

I was wondering is there any formula that can allow me to do: 
I would like Excel to read whatever is in H5 (which is 12-52) and check the following conditions:

```
If H5 equals H4 then take whatever is in N4 and insert it into I5
If H5 equals O4 then take whatever is in U4 and insert it into I5
If H5 equals V4 then take whatever is in AB4 and insert it into I5
If H5 equals AC4 then take whatever is in AI4 and insert it into I5
```

As you can see H5 equals AC4 so take value 80 from AI4 cell and insert it in I5 cell and discard every other conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write following function in I5

```
=if(h5=h4,n4,if(h5=o4,u4,if(h5=v4,ab4,if(h5=ac4,ai4,"error"))))
```

If it does not recognize if then try to replace if with iif

Effectively, I am putting the desired value in truepart and using falsepart for next "if" function until last part where you have not declared what value should go I took liberty to take it as ERROR

Update: function to get max value

```
=max(if(h5=h4,n4,-10000),if(h5=v4,ab4,-10000),if(h5=o4,u4,-10000),if(h5=ac4,ai4,-10000))
```

Here i presumed the -10000 is the value that you are never going to receive... and I can not take error string here as max has to work on it.

No problem here goes the macro code based on my analysis of your requirement:

```
Option Explicit

Function mymax() As String
    Dim value As String
    Dim r, c, pos

    value = -1000
    c = ActiveCell.Column-6
    r = ActiveCell.Row

    For i = c To 299
        pos = 1 + i * 7
        If Cells(r, c) = Cells(r - 1, pos) Then
            If value < Cells(r - 1, pos+6) Then
            value = Cells(r - 1, pos+6)
        End If
    Next

    If value = -1000 Then
        max = "ERROR"
    Else
        max = value
    End If

End Function
```

you call call this function macro life any other excel function:

```
=mymax()
```

Comment: A follow up question what If there are two text matches the condition. Is there any way you can edit this formula so that it can pick up a closest value. For example if text in H5 matches with H3 (it dosent show in that image but assume there is same text as H5 in H3) and AC4 I want formula to pick value from AC4 not H3. To help you out the new value will always be higher than the old one.

Comment: Then the one you used first will win. Remember falsepart is evaluated only if truepart fails

Comment: If the solution worked, please do not forget to accept the answer

Comment: how do i make a max value win? so compare the value from AI5 and other cell and take max value.

Comment: In case of finding max correct value simple if-else can not work. You need to write macro where you will need to use for-next loop to get all correct answer and compare with last correct answer and replace if newer is bigger

Comment: @user3812613 added a solution to get max successful value. Good night. If worked please one upvote.. if you have given already one ;)

Comment: I know you have already answer the question but I have 300 rows and I cannot add 300 formulas (Excel complains). Is there any way you can show me this in form of macro? It will relay help.

Answer (score 1):

=IF(H5=H4,N4,IF(H5=O4,U4,IF(H5=V4,AB4,IF(H5=AC4,AI4,0))))

Comment: While this appears to be the better formula, the OP's statement of *'... H5 equals AC4 so take value 80 from AI4 cell and insert it in I5 cell and discard every other conditions'* seems to indicate that the conditions he/she set forth should be read backwards. Tough to say but that is my interpretation of the *'discard every other conditions'* bit even though there are no other matches.